# Dockerfile: RUN ls -l

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this simple Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8
RUN ls -l
RUN pwd
```

When I build it `docker build . --no-cache` I'm expecting to see the result of the `ls -l` and `pwd` but nothing is shown.

```
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk8@sha256:e8de192088d82fa93e1...
 => [2/3] RUN ls -l
 => [3/3] RUN pwd
 => exporting to image
 => => exporting layers
 => => writing image sha256:ea9d3d5490cea3d73321654a6...
```

I'm using Big Sur with Docker 3.1.0 (just freshly reinstalled). My colleagues are able to see the result of the command.

Comment: Newer versions of Docker have a rewritten build engine; add an option `--progress=plain` or set the environment variable `BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain`.