# how to get detailed logs from docker build (list of files)

Tags: docker

I am using the standard docker command:

docker build -t  XXX -f Dockerfile .

to build my container.  I would like to know if there is a way to get some more detailed logs about which files are being copied into the image.

Alternatively, is there a way from the DockerFile to list the files in a directory to the stdout (commandline from where docker command was run or log to a file).

Unfortunately my container dockerfile is crashing at a later point so I cannot examine the image as it is not being created.

Comment: `RUN ls somedir` not work?

Comment: yes works!  note that I needed ls -l  without -l I do not get the output.  seems that for my version I need to also add --progress plain on the command line (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936425/dockerfile-run-ls-l?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**In short**
Add `RUN ls -la` to your Dockerfile and run it with `docker build --progress=plain --no-cache .`

**More details**
As explained in the comments under the question you can

- Write `RUN ls -la` in your Dockerfile to log the content of the current directory
  (or `RUN ls -la <dir>` for any dir).
- Use `--progress=plain` for your docker build command to show the log

In addition, if you see something like this...

```
#17 [13/17] RUN ls -la
#17 sha256:53da81962480617r33c7xg53172bdcc35xa38713a43dc4012x07937cf66cb24e
#17 CACHED
```

...your log is not written, as the `ls` command is not really run. Instead docker retrieved the result from the cache (written during one of your earlier `docker build` commands).
Use `--no-cache` in that case to ensure your `ls` command really runs.